# How do I create truly dynamic and flexible stylesheets using Angular 2 with interpolation?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, themes

For angular 1 applications, I found it necessary to add theming capabilities, where users could set a few colors in a preferences section of the application, and the application would apply those colors everywhere consistently - buttons,  progress bars - you name it.

With Angular 2, this looks to be rather difficult. For example, if I need to provide colors for weird css selectors - like changing the color on a progress bar - then ngStyle, ngClass or directives cannot fit the bill. What I really need is to dynamically create stylesheets using Angular's interpolation.

I could do this in Angular 1 just fine - I could create a directive and the HTML template would simply be a `style element`, containing all of the colour overrides. This was simple and easy. But Angular 2 doesn't want to cooperate.

```
MyFile.ts:19:12: Unknown word  17 | 
  18 | :host ul li button {
> 19 |   color: {{themeColors.primaryBackground | async}};
     |            ^
  20 |   border: none;
  21 |   border-radius: 25px;
```

Whereas the code below works just fine, but this is not what I'm going for as it won't work in more complex cases:

```
[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: themeColors.primaryBackground | async}"
```

How can I create a dynamic stylesheet that allows me to interpolate values (like using async pipes, etc.) without Angular 2 complaining?

Comment: That's not supported. You can use `ngStyle`. If that is not enough you can add styles imperatively to the document.